# Increment value to attr using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I want to increment the value of i .  The "for" loop does not work.

```
$("a[href$='.xls']").appendTo(".xl1").attr('id','xl'+i);
```

I search all excel files and places them in a container and increment the value of their id.

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("a[href$='.xls']").each(function(i) {
  $(this).appendTo(".xl1").attr('id','xl'+i);
})
```

counting starts from i=0

You can read about function each() here http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: No need to define ´i´ separately: the first argument in the each() callback is the index

Comment: +1 - `each` is probably better here, since the OP is making several actions on every element.

Comment: @Álvaro - you are right, your way is much cleaner and simpler. I edited the answer to take this into account.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery 1.4.2:

```
var i=1;
$("a[href$='.xls']")
   .appendTo(".xl1")
   .attr('id', function(){return 'xl' + i++});
```